# abcpdf 8 .net throwing unhandled exception in w3wp process

Tags: .net, pdf-generation, abcpdf

I'm trying to use ABCPDF.net 8 to create a pdf from html content.

When using the method AddHtml, this works fine.

However, I need to take in the styles too, so I need to use AddImageHtml. But using this method causes the w3wp process to throw an exception. When I debug through the code with Reflector the exception seems to come at different places, making me think it is maybe some kind of memory thing... (nice and specific, I know).

My abcpdf code is as simple as...

```
global::WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc doc = new WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc();

doc.AddImageHtml(test);
```

...and I'm doing this in the page render.

Any one had any experience of abcpdf throwing generic exceptions in the w3wp process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this has something to do with the fact that I have IE9 installed - when I switch abcpdf to use the Gecko rendering engine, everything works...

Comment: How do you switch the rendering engine? Having trouble finding the documentation.

Comment: doc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;

Comment: 'EngineType.Gecko' is to use Firefox rendering Engine. This defaults to installed IE version if not specified. So be careful before use!

Comment: yes switched to Gecko and it worked but only after upgrading to the latest Firefox from v.9 (thought it shouldn't depend on it)