# Render a pdf from a html page

Tags: c#, javascript, html, abcpdf

Hello I have the following code and I am trying to convert a html page into a pdf. I am using abcpdf.

My code is below :

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
    theDoc.Rect.Inset(72, 144);

    theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
    int theID;
    **theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://www.templateworld.com/free_templates.html/");**

    while (true)
    {
        theDoc.FrameRect(); // add a black border
        if (!theDoc.Chainable(theID))
            break;
        theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
        theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= theDoc.PageCount; i++)
    {
        theDoc.PageNumber = i;
        theDoc.Flatten();
    }

    theDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("pagedhtml.pdf"));
    theDoc.Clear();
```

At the following line :

theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://www.templateworld.com/free_templates.html/");

it throws an error saying "HTML render is blank". I tried the same on Firefox and chrome too. I tried using
other urls too. I get the same error.

Anyone know of any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Have you read and ruled-out the troubleshooting steps listed in section 6.7 of their support section? http://www.websupergoo.com/support.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the answers by trueamerican420 and McAden really helped.

I am using ABCPDF version 7 on Internet explorer 10. I removed the update and downgraded to 
internet explorer 9. and everything works perfectly now

Comment: ABCpdf .NET works in the context of the current release of Windows and Acrobat. So it is best to use a current release of ABCpdf on a current version of Windows. Using a version which was discontinued many years ago is inadvisable. Use the current release.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this other Stack Overflow article. Maybe it will help you out.

[ABCPDF6 issue: "HTML render is blank" but web page output is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653365/abcpdf6-issue-html-render-is-blank-but-web-page-output-is-fine)